# Existence proof for adjoint transformation for different inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

One of the answers in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961867/proof-of-uniqueness-of-the-adjoint-operator) gives an existence proof for the adjoint operator

> Existence is straightforward to establish if you have an orthonormal basis, say $e_k$:
>
> Then, with $v= \sum_k v_k e_k$, we have $\langle f(v), w \rangle  = \sum_k \overline{v_k} \langle f(e_k), w \rangle = 
> \langle \sum_k v_k e_k, \sum_k \langle f(e_k), w \rangle e_k \rangle$, that is, $\langle f(v), w \rangle  = \langle v, w' \rangle  $, where 
>   $w'=f^*(w) = \sum_k \langle f(e_k), w \rangle e_k $.

I don't understand how this works if the vector spaces are different, because you could otherwise not equate the right sides of the inner product, $f^*(w) = \sum_k \langle f(e_k), w \rangle e_k$.

Is there something I'm missing that lets you do this. How would you prove this if the inner products were different for the vector spaces?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you think there is here (there isn't actually any problem).  Can you say more precisely what step you think is wrong and why?